# Showing label before setTimeout in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, settimeout

I have a page.html and controller.js file.

I want a label to be shown after typing in a textbox, then after 2 seconds an alert window to pop up and then the label gets hidden again.

So far I have this:

**page.html**

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Calculate</h2>
  <div ng-controller="controller">
    <form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="myFunc()" 
        ng-model-options="{debounce: 200}">

      <label ng-show="showMe">Checking</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('Ctrl', []).controller('controller', function($scope) {

    var alertToCheck = function() {
        alert("Some Message");
        return true;    
    }

    var checked = false;
    $scope.showMe = false;
    $scope.myFunc = function() {

        if(checked == true){
            $scope.cancel(alertToCheck());
            checked = false;
        }
            $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;
            setTimeout(alertToCheck(), 2000);
    };
});
```

The problem is that when I type in the text box, once finished typing I get the alert and then the checking label pops up. I`m not sure what I need to do to get

userfinshestyping -> show label -> pausefor 2 seconds -> show Alertbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your line `setTimeout(alertToCheck(), 2000);` should read `setTimeout(alertToCheck, 2000);`

Placing the () after the function name is causing it to be called immediately